# x64 assembly, ret register and variables

Tags: c++, assembly, 64-bit

I'm relatively new to x64 assembly and im using it in conjunction with VS2010. 
I'm struggling to get a handle on the return values from a proc and I can't really find quality documentation for beginners.

```
.data
 MyByte db 10

 .code
GetValueFromASM proc
mov rax, 28
mov rbx , 19
lea rax, MyByte
mov rax, 10
mov eax, 11
mov ecx, 100

ret
GetValueFromASM endp
end
```

The Ret instruction is printing out the value of eax in my c++ front end, is there some sort of default return register or can you specify it?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" int GetValueFromASM();

int main()
{
    cout << "sup, asm said " <<GetValueFromASM()<<endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

furthermore the instruction mov [reg], MyByte  yields an error, how else do you put a variable into a register?

Comment: According to Wiki, x64 values are returned in `RAX`: 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions

http://left404.com/2011/01/04/moving-x86-assembly-to-64-bit-x86-64/

Answer (score 2):

`ret` doesn't change registers, it's not like the C `return` statement which takes an operand. It's the caller who expects the return value in register `eax`, according to the calling convention. Read about it on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx).

`mov [reg], MyByte` would be a memory-to-memory move which is not supported and would not do what you wanted anyway. You probably want `mov reg, MyByte` without brackets so the value gets put into the register.

Comment: Doesn't `mov reg, mybyte` move the address of `mybyte` into `reg`?

Comment: Ah thanks for the Link, Gives a great deal of insight into the registers, (mov al, MyByte works). I was setting the variable to the incorrect size for the register. Defining MyByte dword 11 and using mov eax, MyByte compiles and outputs correctly. Thank you!